# jQuery in external file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just testing a calculator with some different functions. I got a problem when i move the code to an external js file and then trying to import it. The calculator will not run when i do it this way.

HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div><input id="a1" type="text" value="0" min="0"/></div>
    <div>Velg en:</div>
    <div>Dårlig<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_dårlig"></div>
    <div>Normal<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_normal"></div>
    <div>Bra<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox_bra"></div>
    <select>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Velg en type -- </option>
        <option id="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option id="test2">Test 2</option>
        <option id="test3">Test 3</option>
        <option id="test4">Test 4</option>
        <option id="test5">Test 5</option>
    </select>
    <div>Value: <input id="pris" type="text" value="0" /></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a1').keyup(calculate);
    $(".checkbox_dårlig").change(calculate);
    $(".checkbox_normal").change(calculate);
    $(".checkbox_bra").change(calculate);
    $("select").change(calculate);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        calculate()
    });
});
function calculate(e) { some code }
```

Can someone see where the problem is?

Comment: set the src attribute for your external file.

Comment: Haha damn, yeah when you use autofill. @Hrishikesh Thank you! :)

Comment: This question should be closed/deleted, because this is just a typo and not a real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't import the file. You have to put it in src not type
You have to import it in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, autofill messed it up :)